# Visual Studio SVN project without a Solution?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, visualsvn

I have a professional license for Visual Studio and would like to keep using it as my IDE of choice. Problem is I work in an environment that tends to use Eclipse. The team uses SVN to check code in and out.

I know that VisualSVN will allow me to checkout this project. BUT the project doesn't have a solution tied to it. What is the best way to check out a project that doesn't have a solution tied to it using Visual Studio?

Comment: There really isn't. Visual Studio needs a solution... And a Project File.

Comment: Unless.... You use a Web site Project, that can be bound to a folder. You still need a solution and a Web Site Project in it though, you can keep that on local disk and never check it in.

Comment: Did the method you suggested jessehouwing worked like a charm and I just never check in the solution! Perfect my friend, just Perfect! You should make a post with this on here then I can check it off as solved and give you some credit.

Comment: You may find these helpful: * http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00004/

* http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00002/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a solution and add a Website project to it, you should be able to let Visual Studio work on a folder structure. Just don't check in the project file, nor the solution and you should have basic editing functionality.